# For $\alpha + \beta \;$ limit ordinal, $\alpha, \beta > 0\;$ are ordinals, show that $\beta$ is a limit ordinal

Tags: elementary-set-theory, ordinals

Since $\alpha + \beta $ is a limit ordinal, we have that forall $x\in \alpha + \beta \;$, $x+1\in \alpha + \beta \;$

Lets assume that $\beta\;$ is not a limit ordinal, then there exists some $x\in \beta \;$ such that
$x+1 > \beta $

Although, if   $x\in \beta \;$, then  $x\in \alpha + \beta \;$ but $\;\alpha + \beta \;$ is a limit ordinal, then we get that $x+1\in \alpha + \beta \;$

Since $x+1 > \beta \;$ we get that $\alpha+\beta<\alpha+x+1$.

That's how far I have managed to reach in my general direction of the proof, I wasn't able to conclude any contradiction, altough intuitivly I totally understand why the statement is true.

I would love to get some help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: If $\beta$ is no limit ordinal, it has a maximum, and then $\alpha+\beta$ has a maximum as well since $\alpha+\beta$ is just $\alpha$ with $\beta$ concatenated after it.

Comment: This is pretty much the "proof", but this is so straight forward, I can't find a way to formalize it

Comment: What part of it you want formal? $\alpha + \beta$ is the order type of $A:=(\alpha \times \{0\}) \cup (\beta \times \{1\})$ with the lexicographic order. Show that if $\gamma$ is the maximum of $\beta$, then $(\gamma,1)$ is the maximum of $A$.